# How do I download multiple files from multiple folders over https in python?

Tags: python, download

First off, let me say that I'm fairly new to python. Still not 100% on the terminology. I'm wondering if there is a way to make a download loop for the `.grb2` files from each folder from `https://nomads.ncdc.noaa.gov/data/gfs-avn-hi/201705/` . From each folder I would only need the `0000_000.grb2` files, with the last three zeros increasing by 12.  For example, the first file I would need is `...0000_000.grb2` -> then `0000_012.grb2` etc until `384.grb2`.  Then the program would close the folder and move onto the next one.  Is this a case where `urllib` would come into play?   I

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3?

Comment: I am using python 2

Comment: First you need to decide what "folder" means in the context of HTTP, since it does not define that for you.

Comment: If the url is staying the same and the file name is just increasing incrementally, try doing a `for` loop and just place the number as a string at the filename area of the url.

Comment: Ah GRIB2 files... Simply use a nested `for` loop. The outer loop will loop through the different days (`'/gfs-avn-hi/201705/201705' + outer_loop_number`) and the inner loop will loop through the hours (the model hour). P.S. Python has a package to read grib files, but it can only be used on Linux for the time being.

Comment: I'm still not 100% sure how that would look like in terms of code.  I get what your saying, its  that I just have trouble translating it to code.